# How to redirect a subdomain with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

In my .htaccess I have created a rule that redirects a subdomain to my main domain, but it happens that the subdomains are dynamic, I have put a CNAME record in my hosting towards the domain that identifies that when there is a subdomain I know that it is an alias of the domain main, well up there, then with my .htaccess I want that when the subdomain eg: http://randomsubdomain.example.com redirects to http://example.com, below I leave the above mentioned.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.com/$1 [L]
```

and the record would be this:

```
Name          TTL  Class Type  Record
*.example.com 1200 IN    CNAME example.com
```

The problem I have is that when I try to access a dynamic subdomain it seems that I can't read the .htaccess and the rule is not met, the server shows me a message telling me that this subdomain does not exist.

How would I achieve what I want to do if this is not the right way?